# I cannot show image in PHP

Tags: php, html, image, web, tags

```
I'm new to PHP and coding in general, I already made the same lines of code in HTML and it worked fine but when i move it to PHP it wont load.
```

```
<div class="left">
   <div class="healy-logo">
       <img src="/asset/healy-logo.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="doctor-logo">
       <img src="/asset/doctor authen.png" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what is shown when i run the html code and my expectation for my php file
[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkwWp.png)

But when i run the PHP code it shows an error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZVkD.png)

Comment: try using this `src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/healy-logo.png"`. but make sure you put the file in the asset folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="left">
<div class="healy-logo">
<img src="asset/healy-logo.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="doctor-logo">
<img src="asset/doctor authen.png" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

If you use "/" in starting of a file path, It will take the first directory as the root directory of your system. this takes the relative path of your project directory

Answer (score 0):

i think you just forget to run with Xampp or something like that (dont forget to click run Apache Server), or you just forgot to copy image folder/file on Xampp Folder.
or you just forget to add  . if that all still not working you can do  inside the HTMl and not HTML inside the

example for  inside the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tes!</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: palevioletred;
            color: white;
        }

        table {
            text-align: center ;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">

        <?php
        for ( $i = 10;
              $i <= 100;  
              $i++
        ){

            if ($i % 1) {
                echo '<tr style="background-color: white;">';
            } 

            for ($j = 1;
                 $j <= 100;
                 $j++
            ) {
                echo "<center><td>Arsy I Love You</td></center>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        ?>
        
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

that's from me, hope thats help you bro!